# On Radio Button Click, Hide/Show Div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have two div's inside my modal and I want to hide and show them upon radio button clicks, but they are not working. I am using Bootstrap buttons for radio. Here is my code:

```
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <div class="lr">
                        <div class="rl">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <!-- Project Details Go Here -->
                                <h2>Course Catalogue</h2>
                                <p class="item-intro text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>

                                ****<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="desktop" autocomplete="off" checked="checked" value="1" onclick="show1();"> Desktop
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="mobile" autocomplete="off" value="2" onclick="show2();"> Mobile
  </label>****

</div>
                                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                    <!-- Indicators -->
                                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                                      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                                    </ol>

                                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                                      <div class="carousel-item active">
                                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/1.png" alt="Chania">
                                      </div>

                                      <div class="carousel-item">
                                        <img class="img-fluid"  src="img/2.png" alt="Chania">
                                      </div>

                                      <div class="carousel-item">
                                        <img class="img-fluid"  src="img/3.png" alt="Flower">
                                      </div>

                                      <div class="carousel-item">
                                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/4.png" alt="Flower">
                                      </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Left and right controls -->
                                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>

                                <div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                    <!-- Indicators -->
                                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                      <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                      <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                      <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                                      <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                                    </ol>

                                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                                      <div class="carousel-item active">
                                        <img class="img-fluid" src="bani1.png" alt="Chania">
                                      </div>

                                      <div class="carousel-item">
                                        <img class="img-fluid"  src="bani2.png" alt="Chania">
                                      </div>

                                      <div class="carousel-item">
                                        <img class="img-fluid"  src="bani1.png" alt="Flower">
                                      </div>

                                      <div class="carousel-item">
                                        <img class="img-fluid" src="bani2.png" alt="Flower">
                                      </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Left and right controls -->
                                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>




                                <p>Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae, nostrum, reiciendis facere nemo!</p>
                                <ul class="list-inline">
                                    <li>Date: January 2017</li>
                                    <li>Client: Threads</li>
                                    <li>Category: Illustration</li>
                                </ul>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close Project</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the javascript code:

```
function show1(){
  document.getElementById('myCarousel2').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('myCarousel').style.display = 'block';

}
function show2(){
  document.getElementById('myCarousel2').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('myCarousel').style.display ='none';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var two = document.getElementById('myCarousel2'),
    one = document.getElementById('myCarousel'),
    input1 = document.getElementById('desktop'),
    input2 = document.getElementById('mobile');
 
    input1.addEventListener('click', function() {
      two.style.display = 'none';
      one.style.display = 'block';
    })

    input2.addEventListener('click', function() {
      two.style.display = 'block';
      one.style.display = 'none';
    })
    
    function x(){
      console.log('x');
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                     sdgsdgsdg   
                    </a>
                    
                </div>

<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
        <div class="lr">
          <div class="rl">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <!-- Project Details Go Here -->
              <h2>Course Catalogue</h2>
              <p class="item-intro text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>

              ****
              <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label id='desktop' class="btn btn-primary active">
 <input type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off" checked="checked" value="1"> Desktop
  </label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary" id="mobile" >
    <input type="radio" name="options"  autocomplete="off" value="2"> Mobile
  </label>****

              </div>
              <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->CAROUSEL 1 CONTENT
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                </ol>

                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="img/1.png" alt="Chania">
                  </div>

                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="img/2.png" alt="Chania">
                  </div>

                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="img/3.png" alt="Flower">
                  </div>

                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="img/4.png" alt="Flower">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Left and right controls -->
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
              </div>

              <div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->CAROUSEL 2 CONTENT
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                </ol>

                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="bani1.png" alt="Chania">
                  </div>

                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="bani2.png" alt="Chania">
                  </div>

                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="bani1.png" alt="Flower">
                  </div>

                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="bani2.png" alt="Flower">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Left and right controls -->
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
              </div>




              <p>Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae,
                nostrum, reiciendis facere nemo!</p>
              <ul class="list-inline">
                <li>Date: January 2017</li>
                <li>Client: Threads</li>
                <li>Category: Illustration</li>
              </ul>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close Project</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @LoveneetSaini Deleted `onclick` events on inputs, added text content `CAROUSEL 1/2 CONTENT` and changed `myCarousel1` into `myCarousel`. That's all.

Comment: It;s working if I remove the buttons and use them as simple radio buttons but with bootstrap buttons, the code is not working

Comment: @LoveneetSaini Maybe bootstrap buttons have different `id` or bootstrap overwrites their events? You should post your code with bootstrap.

Comment: I have added bootstrap cdn.. please have a look

Comment: @LoveneetSaini But when I turn on your snippet, it doesn't work at all :( Nothing appears.

Comment: Please click on sdgsdgsdg text to popup the modal

Comment: @LoveneetSaini Okey I've fixed it.

Comment: @LoveneetSaini Great(:

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Bootstrap, you're also using jQuery. Try this:

```
function show1(){
  $('#myCarousel, #myCarousel2').toggle();
}

function show2(){
  $('#myCarousel, #myCarousel2').toggle();
}
```

`.toggle()` will only work the way you want if one of the carousels is hidden by default. Otherwise you can use:

```
function show1(){
  $('#myCarousel2').hide();
  $('#myCarousel').show();
}

function show2(){
  $('#myCarousel2').show();
  $('#myCarousel').hide();
}
```

Also, because modals are hidden by default, it creates a lot of problems.

Try to call the functions the following way:

```
$(document).on("click", "#desktop", function() {
  $('#myCarousel2').hide();
  $('#myCarousel').show();
});

$(document).on("click", "#mobile", function() {
  $('#myCarousel2').show();
  $('#myCarousel').hide();
});
```

Comment: No, it's not working.. Nothing happens when I click on either of the buttons

Comment: @LoveneetSaini See the edit I made to my answer at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Try to set id for your radio-buttons and bind click event:

```
 window.onload = function() {
    var radio1 = document.getElementById('radio1');
    radio1.onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('myCarousel2').style.display ='none';
        document.getElementById('myCarousel').style.display = 'block';
    }
    //...
 }
```